# Azure logic app errors when adding different connectors

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps, azure-logic-apps

I've created a simple Logic App with the following actions:

- Recurrence
- HTTP Get

Next, when I try to add any of the following apps, I get the respective errors:

- Biztalk JSON Encoder ("Error fetching API definition. Code: 404, Message: Resource not found.")
- Onedrive Connector ("Some thing went wrong while getting login uris and token. Error code: resource not found")
- Office365 Connector ("Some thing went wrong while getting login uris and token. Error code: resource not found")

Comment: Can you restart the gateway where the API connectors are?

Comment: I still have this problem on one particular Azure account. Another account seems to work better but with other problems, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30501428/azure-logic-app-how-to-save-http-connectors-body-content-to-onedrive-file

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for those having the same issue:

Recurrence and HTTP Get are integrated into the Logic APP. However, connectors such as Biztalk, Onedrive and Office365 require a new resource (API App) to be created in the resource group. When adding these connectors, the portal is trying to provision new resources.

If your account has permission restrictions, it won't let you create new API Apps. Hence the error "resource not found". You need an account with the proper permissions to provision new API Apps.

Hope that helps.