# Azure Logic App: How to save HTTP Connector's body content to OneDrive file?

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps, azure-logic-apps

I have a simple Azure Logic App with the following components:

- Recurrence
- HTTP Get from HTTPS url

I've tried to configure the next component to save the HTTP response body to OneDrive with OneDrive Connector configured as follows:

- FilePath: ApiTest/test.json
- Content: @{body('http')}
- Content Transfer Encoding: None

This gives the following error:

{"code":"InvalidTemplate","message":"Unable to process template language expressions in action 'microsoftonedriveconnector' inputs at line '1' and column '11': 'Template language expression cannot be evaluated: one of string interpolation segment value has unsupported type 'Object'. Please convert the value to string using the 'string()' function.'."}

If I then use @{string(body('http'))} I get:

{"code":"InvalidTemplate","message":"Unable to process template language expressions in action 'microsoftonedriveconnector' inputs at line '1' and column '11': 'The template language function 'string' was invoked with an invalid parameter. The value cannot be converted to the target type.'."}

How can I use the body of HTTP Connector and save it to One Drive?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer, but I am wrestling with this very issue right now.  I will post if I find a solution and would be very interested in case any one else finds a solution.  I do find one thing interesting.  There is a header and body option on the consuming end of my Http Connector which works when it runs.  The error (as the above poster notes) occurs when passing that value to the next card.  But, when I look at the output (link) on the run tab, I see a json value for the header and for the body.  Does this need to be wrapped in a json parser?

Comment: @body('http') seems to fix this immediate error (i.e. without the brackets - @{body('http')}).  But, it leads me to another error...but I think that is how I am receiving it on my next card.  Does this work for you or get you past the error you posted?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me just fine and generated the file in the /random/test.txt folder, however I believe the problem in your case is that you are downloading a JSON file which is causing it to be interpreted as an object by the engine. 
I'll follow up with the team and maybe we need a "ToJson" call, or a way to "Passthrough", or make "String" more "flexible" (though that could be weird).

```
                "fileContent": {
                    "Content": "@{body('http')}",
                    "ContentTransferEncoding": "None"
                },
```

Actions in code view looks like:

```
"http": {
        "type": "Http",
        "inputs": {
            "method": "GET",
            "uri": "http://www.carlosag.net/"
        },
        "conditions": []
    },
    "microsoftonedriveconnector": {
        "type": "ApiApp",
        "inputs": {
            "apiVersion": "2015-01-14",
            "host": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/zzz/providers/Microsoft.AppService/apiApps/MicrosoftOneDriveConnector",
                "gateway": "https://yyy.azurewebsites.net"
            },
            "operation": "UploadFile",
            "parameters": {
                "filePath": "random/test.json",
                "fileContent": {
                    "Content": "@{body('http')}",
                    "ContentTransferEncoding": "None"
                },
                "overwrite": true
            },
            "authentication": {
                "type": "Raw",
                "scheme": "Zumo",
                "parameter": "@parameters('/subscriptions/...')"
            }
        },
```

Comment: Yes, it seems application/json response doesn't work the same way.

I think you're doing something wrong here. It should be possible to get the data blob from HTTP regardless of the content type (here json). You should not make json any special. This is really, really confusing. Please fix it.

Comment: I addition, if I try to HTTP GET a PNG file and store it to OneDrive using the same method, the file gets broken.

Comment: I believe for the PNG you should set the Content Type to be Base64 encoded which will make it work

Answer (score 0):

You should try "@body('http')". I believe this will work. "@{body('http')}" is a form of string interpolation: expected output value is string and not a JSON.

Comment: No it doesn't. The response is application/json and Azure handles it in some weird way.

Answer (score 0):

I initialized a String variable 'Content' and set the value to the body of the HTTP.

@{body('HTTP')}

And then I convert the String to JSON to read the desired node with an expression.

json(variables('Content'))?['ExcelFile']

I went a step further and base64 decoded to binary in order to upload to Sharepoint. Going to OneDrive would likely be the same.

base64ToBinary(json(variables('Content'))?['ExcelFile'])